# Is it possible to adjust mat-form-field-outline thickness?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I'm trying to style angular material's input to look the same as all inputs in this app.

Is it possible to adjust the thickness of the schedule's input outline to have the same width as the project's input border?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The classes to override are:

```
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline-thick .mat-form-field-outline-start,
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline-thick .mat-form-field-outline-end,
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline-thick .mat-form-field-outline-gap {
    border-width: 1px !important;
}
```

Make sure you use `border-width` and not `border`

Comment: This only changes the input's border during the mouse-hover state. Is there a way to apply this border as the input's default state (ie before the user mouses over the input)?

Comment: It's the same concept as in the answer above, just replace the classes and styles of the input at the state you want to handle. start with finding the relevant classes to modify.

Comment: If anyone is still using `::ng-deep`, remember to use it before _each_ of these selections.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried editing the width of the schedule input itself?

If simply nothing changes maybe try to add the `!important` tag to css to overwrite the width given (and match the other input ones).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
.mat-form-field-outline-start, .mat-form-field-outline-end, .mat-form-field-outline-gap {
  border-width: 2px !important;
}
```